# Finding the Error Approximation Using the Remainder Estimate for the Integral Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^∞  = \frac{1}{n(ln(n)^4)}$

the error in the approximation s≈sn (where s is the value of the infinite sum and sn is the n-th partial sum) is|s−sn|≤ ?

My first misunderstanding is regarding the difference between the infinite sum and the sum to the n-th term is. Aren't these two values technically the same? If n is ∞ wouldn't the value of the infinite sum be the same as the value of the nth partial sum since the nth term is ∞?

Integral Test:

$\int\limits_{n=2}^∞  = \frac{1}{n(ln(n)^4)} dn$

Let u = ln(n)
du = $\frac{1}{n}$

$\int\limits_{n=2}^∞  = \frac{1}{n(u^4)}dx$

$\int\limits_{n=2}^∞  = u^-4 (du)$

$\int\limits_{n=2}^∞  = -\frac{1}{3(u^3)}$

$\int\limits_{n=2}^∞  = -\frac{1}{3(ln(n)^3)}$

$\lim\limits_{n->∞}  = -\frac{1}{3(ln(n)^3)}$

=$\lim\limits_{n->∞}  = -\frac{1}{3(ln(2)^3)}$

This value is the infinite sum I believe. If I subtract from it the partial sum 
then it would be 0.

Comment: (1) For starters, I'm afraid you don't know and don't understand the basic mathematical notation of sum, integrals, limits, and what the "$=$" means and how to use it appropriately. For example, what do you mean by "$\int\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} =\frac{1}{n(u^4)}$"??? (2) Next, what is the definition of the sum of an infinite series? If you take a moment to read the definition, you'll find the answer to your question "Aren't these two values [the infinite sum and the sum to the $n$-th term] technically the same?"

Comment: Is it then the first 2 terms?

Comment: Or just the sum when n=2?

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n\log^4 n}$ is convergent (by [Cauchy  condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)) but it converges very slowly. The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x\log^4 x}$ is continuous, positive and decreasing on $(2,+\infty)$, hence

$$ \sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{n\log^4 n}\leq \int_{N-1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x\log^4 x}=\frac{1}{3\log^3(N-1)} $$
and
$$ \sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{n\log^4 n}\geq \int_{N}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x\log^4 x}=\frac{1}{3\log^3(N)}. $$